# StageVideo landscape on portrait screen with autoOrients = false

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I am trying to display landscape in adobe air (ios/android) stage video when the screen is portrait and the autoOrients = false 
Can I rotate the video?
Or do other manipulation that will case the video to rotate?

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly easy.  Before you encode the video just turn it on its side.*Then* encode it.  So that when it opens it will open like this in your portrait-mode app: [image]

Then just add it to your media assets in the usual way. When it plays just turn your phone 90 degrees! When finished, turn back to the rest of your portrait-mode material.

If your video already exists and you don't have access to, say, Adobe After Effects in order to make the rotation, you can rotate it with **iMovie** on a Mac, **Windows Live Movie Maker** on Windows, or even through some web sites that do this as a service.

Comment: This is a great hack but is there a way to rotate it on the fly without encode it especially for that.

Comment: Your meaning is not quite clear. Do you WANT the video to open, scaled down, so that it's length fits across the width of the portrait-mode screen? And then push a button to rotate and scale-up the video? You can do this with Video-Class video instances, but not StageVideo.  By the way, in my answer, above, don't forget to define the StageVideo viewport as a vertical rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

When you locked autoOrients (false) - you can't receive StageOrientationEvent event so you can't change/read current orientation and this is fully correct.

I can assume that you can using Accelerometer detect angle of your device and emulate orientation changing. In this case you can update stageVideo viewPort frame and video may automatically fits to the frame. But you can't rotate it. Just change width/height depending for pseudo-orientation.